# At the office or in the office

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> I will be at the office at 9.

Or

> I will be in the office at 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context. Stating that you will be at the office at 9 implies that you shall arrive at 9. However, stating that you will be in the office at 9 implies that you shall continue to be in the office at 9.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.  [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20office%2Cin%20the%20office&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cat%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20the%20Office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20Office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20the%20Office%3B%2Cc0) shows that "in the office" is about twice as popular as "at the office".