# "in my office" vs. "at my office"

Tags: meaning

consider the following sentences

> last night, I had a meeting in my office
>
> last night, I had a meeting at my office

[At the office or in the office](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/109670/108867) clearly says both of them are correct.

Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Pretty much. Perhaps _in my office_ makes it plainer that the meeting was in the particular room where the speaker's desk is.

Comment: @KateBunting, Agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a colloquial sense, you'd say 'in my office' to denote the specificity of the location of the meeting, whereas you'd say 'at my office' to generally denote the general sense of having a meeting at work.
However, this is a personal interpretation based on experience. It should not be taken dogmatically.

Comment: We have been taught in Indian schools that 'at' is for a relatively small one, and 'in' for bigger. We can meet at Connaught Place in Delhi. Still, some styles go on like at home, at school, at the office, etc. Even when the village is small, 'in the village' is often used. Again contexts.

Comment: @RamPillai That convention applies particularly to named towns/cities rather than general locations like 'the office'.

Answer (score -1):

I would use both of them is interchangeable in this sentience, but `at` probably more accurate.

To know why, here is some explanation:

- Use `at` to talk about locations at companies, workplaces when we see them as a place of activity: How many people are working **at** Microsoft?
- Use `in` to talk about locations within a larger area compared with the object: I know my book is somewhere **in** this room. Can anyone see it?

[Reference and more information](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place)